# Download file from NAS attached to server through http

Tags: php, nas

I have many files stored in a NAS. The NAS is attached to a server as network drive (lets say, it is on Y://).

I use xampp to serve my application built in php. The application was built to serve users to download the files from NAS, directly through http instead of ftp.

So can I set the files from NAS, so it can be downloaded by using http URL, like example.com/files/the-file.zip ?

The xampp is located at C:// directory

Note: The xampp htdocs has already set to accessed by a domain. So it is not domain pointing problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pointing domain name to server ip running XAMPP and wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24845562/pointing-domain-name-to-server-ip-running-xampp-and-wordpress)

Comment: No, I think it is different case

Answer (score 1):

You could try so through PHP:

```
<?php
$downloadFolder = 'Y:/';

$fileName = $downloadFolder . $_GET['file'];
$sanitizedFileName = realpath($fileName);

if($fileName !== $sanitizedFileName) {
  throw new RuntimeException('Someone tried to escape');
}

// As seen in http://php.net/readfile:
if (file_exists($fileName)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($fileName).'"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($fileName));
    readfile($fileName);
    exit;
}
```

Or find a way to run everything through .htaccess, but that might give you less control over security handling (probably, you don't want to serve files from other directories or other drives)

Comment: Thanks! But I am just curious what is the function of checking sanitized file? Because I always get that error. But after I commented that line, the file is downloaded. But it is corrupted. So what is the problem now? FYI, the files are huge (in GB)

Comment: Ah! It works now! I add ob_get_clean() and ob_flush() before and after readfile()

Comment: And we need to add double backslash in the $downloadFolder, instead of single slash. It works now!